# Is it possible to import LaTeX document (with formating) into Google-docs?

Tags: google-docs, import, latex, google-docs-template

I prepared a resume / CV using moderncv (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter) in LaTeX.
Is there any possibility to import my document into Google-Docs? Since LaTeX is plain text, I am asking about import with some formating, not just copying raw text from `.tex` fike.

If it is not possible, maybe there's a template similar to moderncv, so that moving to Google Docs will be easier (by writing some script / macro).